# How to get specific fields on document MangoDB&Mongoose and aggregate some of the fields?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"61717cafd351f3ae8b6d205a",
      "restaurant":"Hogwarts",
      "purchasedAt":"2021-10-20T17:47:40.166Z",
      "products":[
         {
            "name":"Meat Samosa",
            "price":3.95,
            "quantity":1,
            "_id":"61717cafd351f3ae8b6d205b"
         },
         {
            "name":"Pilau Rice",
            "price":2.95,
            "quantity":1,
            "_id":"61717cafd351f3ae8b6d205f"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"61717cb2d351f3ae8b6dd05b",
      "restaurant":"Hogwarts",
      "purchasedAt":"2021-10-20T03:14:11.111Z",
      "products":[
         {
            "name":"Pilau Rice",
            "price":2.95,
            "quantity":1,
            "_id":"61717cb2d351f3ae8b6dd05d"
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

I am trying to find a query that will get me all the products (no duplicates) and their quantities added up. Notice that the products id are different even when they are the same(same name) Ideally my response would look like this

```
[
  { 
    name: "Meat Samosa",
    price: 3.95,
    quantity: 1
 },
 {
   name: "Pilau Rice",
   price: 2.95,
   quantity: 2
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `products` array
- `$group` by `name` and get the first `price` and count the `quantity` sum
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      products: 1
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$products.name",
      price: { $first: "$products.price" },
      quantity: { $sum: "$products.quantity" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      price: 1,
      quantity: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jQt39OXbeKv)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! May I ask, how could I sort the aggregated result in descending order based on the quantity field?

Comment: You can use `$sort` stage at last `{ $sort: { quantity: -1 } }`, for descending order -1 and for ascending 1.

Comment: How would you go about returnig only products purchased from two days ago? As well as including the `restaurant` and `purchasedAt` fields in the response?